# Metasploitable virtualbox has wrong keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

I just installed [Metasploitable](https://sourceforge.net/projects/metasploitable/) in VirtualBox for doing some exercises.

Metasploitable is a Ubuntu Hardy-based system, with some built in errors that allows you to tamper with it.

I live in Denmark, and thus I use a Danish keyboard layout.
Since Metasploitable works for English, this means that my keyboard is now messed up a little bit when I type inside of this new VM.

Usually, when I have been working on Ubuntu or Kali VMs, then it is quite easy to navigate around and change the keyboard language layout.

This is harder now, since I only have a terminal to work with.

I have been searching around for solutions, the closest thing I have found is this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Where I think I need to put the configuration I want in the `keyboard-configuration` field. But I don't know how to figure what the configurations are called for the different languages (trying intuitive names like "dk" fails).
So, how do I change the keyboard layout?

Answer (score 0):

Applying [this](https://superuser.com/questions/316230/changing-the-current-set-locale-on-a-linuxubuntu) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes); command `export LANG=da_DK` or `export LANG=da_DA` should do the trick. To make the change permanent edit .profile -file as per instruction in the first link.